# Can't unmount GoogleDrive (Resource busy)

Tags: macos, google-apps

I have a problem to unmount Google Drive volume. I opened a file, Google Drive crashed and I couldn't connect again. I deleted the `~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/DiveFS` folder. But no change. Then I look in /Volumes and I see two volumes. `GoogleDrive` and `GoogleDrive-103360267886788815788`. I try to eject them with `hdiutil`

```
$ hdiutil unmount -force /Volumes/GoogleDrive
hdiutil: unmount: "/Volumes/GoogleDrive" failed to unmount due to error 49168.
hdiutil: unmount failed - Resource busy
```

But it's impossible. I connect to another session that has never been connected to Google Drive and I keep seeing these volumes (of course I rebooted the computer). I did an `lsof /Volumes/GoogleDrive/*`. And there again nothing is displayed.

How do I know which resource is using these volumes?

Comment: Would you like to know how to unmount the drive, or which resource is using the volumes?

Comment: Both would be interesting

Comment: Multiple questions in one generally should be asked as separate questions. This makes it easier to get an answer to one or the other, or possibly both.